# are these two logic level shifters are doing the same job

Tags: mobile-robot

I am just in need of a level shifter and I want to ask if these two are doing the same job without any difference, if there is a difference I need to know

1 : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009

2 : https://www.pololu.com/product/2595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, they are pretty much the same thing.
The schematics are the same.
Specs listed in for the Pololu seems broader; but, that may be just specsmanshio